# Recursive function does not return array

Tags: php, wordpress, function, recursion

I have written the function below to return parent id's of all categories in Worpress by category id. Everything works fine except it does not return the array... Any suggestions would be great! :-)

```
$current_category = (int) $_GET['current_category'];
$cat_ids = array($current_category);

function getParentCatIds($current_category,$cat_ids){
    $child = get_category($current_category);
    $parent_id = $child->parent;
    if($parent_id !== 0){
        array_push($cat_ids, $parent_id);
        getParentCatIds($parent_id,$cat_ids);
    }else{
        var_dump($cat_ids); // <--- this returns the right array
        return $cat_ids; // <--- this returns NULL
    }
}

if($current_category){
    $cat_ids = getParentCatIds($current_category,$cat_ids);
    var_dump($cat_ids); // <--- this returns NULL
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getParentCatIds()` (line 9), you didn't do anything with the return of the function. You should assign it or return it.

Comment: It only returns when parent_id = 0 see line 7. So that would be no problem. The top level is 0. The return is on line 12.

Comment: My mistake! You are so right! The return was the fix! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should always *sanitize* input. A good starting point is [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). Using the right flags for [validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) and [sanitization](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and makes your input save(r). Keep in mind that `FILTER_VALIDATE_*` only tells you if something is valid, while `FILTER_SANITIZE_*` actually cleans your data from unwanted and potentially malicious data.

```
$currentCat = intval( $_GET['current_category'] );
$currentCat = filter_var( $currentCat, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
if ( empty( $currentCat ) ) {
    // Abort – no valid data
    return;
}
```

Then you can build an array, containing your original Category parent ID. This you can pass to `array_walk()`, with a callback as second parameter. The callback itself has assigned a collecting/ final array that is passed as reference and serves as target for your results. Now you can loop recursively over an indefineatly nested WordPress category hierarchy.

```
// Base array
$parents = [];
$callback = function( $index, $id ) use ( &$parent ) {
    0 !== get_category( $id )->parent and $parents[] = $id;
};
array_walk( [ get_category( $currentCat )->parent ], $callback );
```

Comment: Thanx! For the feedback... Are you saying that (int) $_GET['current_category'] is not safe? $_GET['current_category'] is a number when I cast it to an int it would be zero or the correct number? Or am I missing something? Sanitation would not be necessary?

Comment: @DesignBytes There are a lot of things that can be a number – for e.g. an IP address. You should always validate and sanitize input.

Answer (score -4):

## 1) You should have asked at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

2) I think solution is: on line `9` , instead of 

 `getParentCatIds($parent_id,$cat_ids);` 
you should have
 `return getParentCatIds($parent_id,$cat_ids);`

Comment: I can't believe that you have 13.5 K points and giving such replies :/

Comment: Great pointer! It is more a general php question than a Wordpress question. That's why I post it here... :-)

Comment: @HyderB. You dont have to believe :) 
Deisgn Bytes - you've made a small mistake that you have asked here, and i just advised to post it on appropriate place. There are posted PHP questions too, with more advanced knowledge of WP related functions. I've updated answer.

Comment: There are close vote flags for this. And the last thing you should do is to use (1) an answer to **push** people at this (2) headline markup to stand out (this is public shaming) and (3) CAPS LOCK (which you gladly left out).

Comment: My mistake! You are so right! The return was the fix! :-)

Comment: Did not downvote your answer... I just gave you an upvote! Thank you for your help.